# sqlite3 (via python): many to many relationship: trying to do an 'AND' query. Do it with a single SELECT statement or should I do mutliple statements?

Tags: sqlite, many-to-many

I am writing a digital asset management system where assets may have multiple keywords associated with each asset.

I have three tables:

```
assets <- specific information for a single "asset"
keywords <- a list of keywords
assets_keywords <- maps assets to keywords
```

There is a many to many relationship between keywords and assets. Here are the commands that I have used to create the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE assets (asset_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, uri_path TEXT NOT NULL, name TEXT NOT NULL, parent_d TEXT NOT NULL, asset_d TEXT NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE keywords (keyword_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, keyword TEXT NOT NULL, UNIQUE (KEYWORD));

CREATE TABLE assets_keywords (asset_id integer, keyword_id integer, primary key (asset_id, keyword_id));
```

If I want to select assets by keyword, I can only figure out how to do an OR query.

Let's say I want to find an asset that is either BIG ***OR*** SCARY. To do that I can use the following query:

```
SELECT assets.asset_id FROM assets JOIN assets_keywords ON assets.asset_id = assets_keywords.asset_id JOIN keywords ON keywords.keyword_id = assets_keywords.keyword_id WHERE keywords.keyword = 'BIG' OR keywords.keyword = 'SCARY';
```

But if I want an asset that is both "BIG" ***AND*** "SCARY" I cannot figure out how to structure that statement. The following does not work. Or, rather, it does not return any data - which makes sense to me since a single field can only contain a single keyword. But I don't know how else to structure the query:

```
SELECT assets.asset_id FROM assets JOIN assets_keywords ON assets.asset_id = assets_keywords.asset_id JOIN keywords ON keywords.keyword_id = assets_keywords.keyword_id WHERE keywords.keyword = 'BIG' AND keywords.keyword = 'SCARY';
```

Is there a way to structure this as a single SELECT statement? Or should I run multiple SELECT statements and then use code to find the union of these sets? (I am using python)

Comment: You may use subquery like `select asset_id, count(1) c from AK join K where big or scary` and then join this to assets and take with c == 2

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am trying to comprehend what this query does. I think this query by itself will return a row with an asset_id and a count of how many rows matched the query. If an asset_id has both of these keywords then the count should be 2. But I think the join is breaking this logic. I am getting a count of 18. And if I run the query with `*` instead of `asset_id, count(1) c` I do actually get a table back with 18 rows.

Comment: I was able to get this to more or less work: `select asset_id from (SELECT asset_id, count(*) c FROM assets_keywords WHERE keyword_id IN (SELECT keyword_id FROM keywords WHERE keyword = 'BIG' OR keyword = 'SCARY') GROUP BY asset_id) WHERE c = 2;`  I would not have been able to do that without your help. Thanks!

Comment: in fact it can be even simpler (if you just wana assets ids) `SELECT AK.asset_id FROM assets_keywords AK INNER JOIN keywords K ON K.keyword_id = AK.keyword_id
WHERE K.keyword = 'BIG' OR K.keyword = 'SCARY'
GROUP BY AK.asset_id
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1`  ... aggregates (count, max, etc,,) require `GROUP BY` SQLite  is less strict about it but still  you should use it

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you. I am still working my way through exactly what it is doing but that is what the docs are for. Thanks for your help! If you want to put this as an actual reply to the original post I will mark it as the solution.